# Should I code my own numeric keyboard? It's bad UX?

Tags: keyboard

I'm building my first app in Html/Css/Js and I need the numeric keyboard in one screen. I have some apparently solvable problems with the standard keyboard, mostly because I don't like the aesthetic, and I am considering the possibility to code a simple and 'beautiful' numeric keyboard. My doubt is if it can hinder the user experience.

Any advice?

Thanks,
Borja

Comment: Are you planning on replacing a numeric keypad style that the user is familiar with, one that they perhaps use in multiple other applications daily, or is what you're looking to replace only ever used in this one place?

Comment: This is similar to debates about whether QWERTY, Dvorak or Colemak is a more ergonomic and efficient keyboard layout. I think it might be application specific but in general you need a good reason to defy convention (unless it is convention for convention sake only).

Comment: There's a broader question...why have an on-screen keyboard of your own making at all? What's the problem you are trying to solve here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you keep the placements of the numbers unchanged, it should be fine. besides the aesthetics, don't change anything else. Users are used to using numeric key pads in their daily activities like phones, atms, access numbers, etc and are VERY used to the standard numeric keypad layout.

Comment: Look at a phone then look at a calculator. There is no standard numeric keypad layout. :)

Comment: @DA01: the layouts for phones and calculators may be different, but the one in Android phones is the same in all Android phones, the one on calculators is the same on all calculators, etc. So, there still is a "standard" layout to stick to depending on the platform you are targetting.